Superspace calculation: Converting the Kahler potential to superpotential?
In the Lecture notes of Tachikawa on 4d ${\cal N}=1$, in equation (3.2.12), which reads
\begin{equation}
    \int d^4 \theta \delta K = - \frac{1}{2} \int d^2 \theta \overline{D}^2 \delta K + c.c.\tag{3.2.12}
\end{equation}
there is a conversion of the Kahler potential to a superpotential. This is the key to obtaining the beta function of superpotential, which is not renormalized in the holomorphic scheme. How to derive this?
Note that this is related to the two different forms of the kinematic term of the gauge field. The standard construction in 4d is the superpotential:
\begin{equation}
    \int d^2 \theta \frac{-i}{8\pi} \tau \operatorname{tr} W_\alpha W^\alpha  + c.c.
\end{equation}
However, in the book Mirror Symmetry by Hori and Vafa, the construction is the Kahler potential in (15.35)
\begin{equation}
    - \frac{1}{2e^2} \int d^4 \theta \bar{\Sigma} \Sigma
\end{equation}
There are 3 derivatives in $W_\alpha$ and 2 derivatives in $\Sigma$.
